# Oracle SQL REPLACE '['

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I am trying to make changes to a "FORMULA" column in a table with SQL using REPLACE(FORMULA, '[H2]', '(2H)'); but it doesn't change the [H2] text.  Going the other direction, REPLACE(FORMULA, '(H2)', '[2H]'); works fine.
I have to assume that '[' and ']' have special meanings in Oracle SQL, though I've not been able to find clues yet.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: *Suggestions welcome* isn't a question.

Comment: Are you sure this is reproducible?  I would expect this problem with `regex_replace` but not ordinary `replace`.

Comment: Show your complete script.

Comment: Tim is correct; the problem was not reproducible.  I'm not sure of the original cause, but suspect either the records were locked or commit was not being executed.  It now REPLACES correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to replace only [H2] to (2H) or everything like [AB122] TO (122AB) ?

if only [H2] then

```
with datas as ( select '[AA2][AH33][H2][AH267]' AS FORMULA FROM DUAL )
select REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMULA,'\[H2\]','(2H)') from datas;
```

if Everything then

```
with datas as ( select '[AA2][AH33][AH267]' AS FORMULA FROM DUAL )
select REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMULA,'\[([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)\]','(\2\1)') from datas;
```

Now without some sample data, it's hard to make sure that it fits all your cases

PS : your original replace works on my database